# Avoiding a double free() error when deleting separate Linked Lists that contain the same object

Tags: c, memory-management, linked-list

I am working on a personal project and have run into a conceptual problem. How should I go about deleting multiple dynamically created linked lists that could have references to the same dynamically created object?

I have some function that returns a dynamically created linked list that houses dynamically created objects.

```
List* generate_list() {
  Object* object_address = create_object();
  List* list = create_list();
  list_append_end(list, object_address);
  return list;
}
```

I have another function that deletes the linked list and recursively deletes the objects stored inside the linked list by providing a delete function.

```
List* list = generate_list();
delete_list(list, delete_object_function);
```

Now, I run into a problem with this approach when trying to delete multiple linked lists that hold references to the same object.

```
Object* object_address = create_object();
List* list = create_list();
List* another_list = create_list();
list_append_end(list, object_address);
list_append_end(another_list, object_address);
delete_list(list, delete_object_function);
delete_list(another_list, delete_object_function); // Double free() would occur here
```

I could obviously just not delete one of the two lists to avoid a double free() error, but that could create a memory leak later down the line.

My actual code is much more involved than this, but I tried to make a simplified example. Not sure how to avoid this situation.

Comment: One classical solution is reference counting. Have a function to get a refence to an object which increments the count. Then in the delete function decrement the count and free if it gets to 0.

Comment: How do you include the nodes in the lists? Do you have `next` pointers included in the nodes directly? Or do you have dedicated list nodes that only point to your real data objects?

Comment: You could make a copy of the object every time you add it to the list.  Then you wouldn't have to keep track of how many lists it resides in.

Comment: Are you using malloc() and free()?

Comment: There was already a comment about using reference counting. However, what it will amount to is that you will have to do memory management yourself. If it was possible to inspect the results of free() and malloc(), you could decide if a block was already returned and skip freeing it again. However, free() and malloc() are implementation dependent, and thus such a solution is not portable. In that case you need to do your own memory management, which mostly means that you always should be able to keep and inspect the state of your allocated objects.

Comment: At what moment do you want the object to be destroyed? When you delete the first list (ie an object is destroyed as soon as a list owning it is destroyed) on when you delete the second list (ie an object is destroyed when no list owns it)? The second way is implemented with ref counting and is already described in an answer, the first one involves a proxy that is the real owner of the object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use reference counting.  Whenever a new owner is added to the object, one must increment the refcouter with `get_object()`. When ownership is released with `put_object()` reduce the counter.Free the objects only when the counter reaches `0`.

```
struct {
...
int refcount;
} Object;

Object* create_object(void) {
  ...
  obj->refcount = 1;
  return obj;
}

Object* get_object(Object* obj) {
  assert(obj->refcount > 0);
  obj->refcount++;
  return obj;
}

void put_object(Object* obj) {
  assert(obj->refcount > 0);
  obj->refcount--;
  if (obj->refcount == 0) {
    delete_object(obj);
  }
}
```

It's safe because `get_object()` can only be called when the caller owns the object. Thus object's `refcount` would be non-zero.

When the refcount reaches `0` then there can be no other owner of the object, so no one can call `get_object()`.

now the usage could look like:

```
Object* obj = create_object();
List* list = create_list();
List* another_list = create_list();
// let `list` own the object
list_append_end(list, get_object(obj));
// let `another_list` own the object as well
list_append_end(another_list, get_object(obj));
delete_list(list, put_object);
delete_list(another_list, put_object);
put_object(obj); // release ownership because `obj` goes out of scope
```

Note that the last three operations can be executed in any order.

BTW.
It's a good practice is set a pointer to an object to `NULL` after releasing the ownership.

---

In the original `generate_list()` function there is no need to add extra `get_object`/`put_objects` calls because the ownership of object pointed by `object_address` can be implicitly *passed* from `object_address` variable to the returned `list`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'll be sure to implement reference counts for my C objects in the future!